# Background picture not loading

Tags: html, css

I was creating a very simple HTML page with a full-size background, however, my background picture displayed as broken when I loaded the page. Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening please? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .bgimg {
      min-height: 100%;
      min-width: 1024px;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    .vdeo {margin: 10% 8%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="bgimg" src="https://wallpaperclicker.com/wallpaper/HD-Happy-Birthday-Cartoon-Wallpaper/20306228/">
    <iframe class="vdeo" width="600" height="345" align="middle" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXX?autoplay=1&controls=0"></iframe>
      <script>
      for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
        alert(
          (i===2)?"Happy Birthday, dear Hub Hub!":"Happy Birthday to YOU!"
        )
      }
      </script>
</iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my page looks as in the picture:[my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLPnV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load a web page as a background image.

https://wallpaperclicker.com/wallpaper/HD-Happy-Birthday-Cartoon-Wallpaper/20306228/

Unless you're using a server application to select and serve an image, your `src` attribute value should end with an image filename extension, such as .jpg or .png.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn why "thank you" comments are discouraged and how you should show gratitude instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put the link to the site **with** the picture, you need the link to the picture. (In your case it's https://wallpaperclicker.com/storage/wallpaper/HD-Happy-Birthday-Cartoon-Wallpaper-20306228.jpg) Try it with the direct link to the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a URI on the `src` attribute value that renders an entire web page, if you want to use the image inside that web page, you should use the image URL.

In this case I guess it is: https://wallpaperclicker.com/storage/wallpaper/HD-Happy-Birthday-Cartoon-Wallpaper-20306228.jpg

If you're not managing the routes of that website, you can right-click then inspect and see the image source.